# How do you scroll this on Bilibili.com with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to scroll an element that includes comments of a video on Bilibili.com.

Example URL here: https://www.bilibili.com/video//?spm_id_from=333.334.chief_recommend.16

The comment area is in the right of page.

I tried to run following four JavaScript expressions.

```
document.querySelector('#mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical > div > div.mCSB_draggerRail').scrollBy(0, 100)
document.querySelector('#mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical > div > div.mCSB_draggerRail').scrollTop += 100;
document.querySelector('li[dmno="1"]').scrollBy(0, 100)
document.querySelector('li[dmno="1"]').scrollTop += 100;
```

But none of them work.

How would you do it?

### Edit

Oh, I'm sorry. I posted mistaken URL.

Not correct: : https://www.bilibili.com/video//?spm_id_from=333.334.chief_recommend.16

corrent: https://www.bilibili.com/video/av31026102/?spm_id_from=333.334.chief_recommend.16

@tadman No error occured. Each JavaScript output just "undefined" or "100" like following.

```
document.querySelector('#mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical > div > div.mCSB_draggerRail').scrollBy(0, 100)
# => undefined
document.querySelector('#mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical > div > div.mCSB_draggerRail').scrollTop += 100;
# => 100
document.querySelector('li[dmno="1"]').scrollBy(0, 100)
# => undefined
document.querySelector('li[dmno="1"]').scrollTop += 100;
# => 100
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic to help you with. Do you get JavaScript errors? If so, what are they specifically?

Comment: Your `document.querySelector('#mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical > div > div.mCSB_draggerRail')` selector returns null on the page you linked. First get that handled. For that you might need a tour on [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)